# Native validation rules does not run while using callback validation rules while using HMVC by WiredDesignz in codeigniter 3.1.3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, callback, codeigniter-hmvc

I recently noticed this weird bug in CI(3.1.3 but might as well be present in other versions). The navtive validation rules like required, valid_email etc don't run while I use the callback. I've already built a My_Form_validation library to make the callback validation rules work with HMVC.
But that seems to create another bug in the form_validation library.
For eg. I've the following validation rules setup:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email",'required|valid_email|callback__validate_credentials|callback__check_user_status');
```

The validation rules should be run in the order they are stated, but the validation rules goes straight to validating the callbacks without checking the "required" and "valid_email" rules. These native validation rules run as they should if I remove the callbacks. Has anybody found a fix around this?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTztVbjwjmE

Comment: I've already used the ur solution to make the callbacks work. My problem is the native validation rules not working (rather than the callbacks not working) while using together with callback.

Comment: Yes. I too found this issue. so, i just splited the validation. eg:  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email",'required|valid_email');   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email",'callback__validate_credentials');   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email",'callback__check_user_status');

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. The native validation still don't run after splitting up the rules.